# How to create libGdx based library

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I want to create my own library which will use libgdx framework. As a result I want to get jar of my library which can be added to any other project which also uses libgdx.

The problem is that I can't find any tutorial how to do it. I can create normal libgdx project, but how I can get jar library from it? Maybe I need to create gradle based project and compile libgdx dependencies?

If somebody has experience in creating libgdx based libraries or extensions, please share your experience.

Comment: Did you check this article http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html it has detailed steps on building JAR files in Android and i am sure it will be the same for libgdx

Comment: Thanks for link, I know how to create libraries in Android, but libgdx is cross-platform. It is not regular Android or java project libgdx has lots of dependencies and extensions and it is very difficult to create regular libgdx project without gradle. In any case I almost finished to figure out will post the working solution soon.

Comment: Alon, did you have any chance to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, I found solution, but I don't know how to simplify and post it here(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is a little old but for others that may stumble here; [This](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/) is the best solution I've found for creating/using your own library project in another LibGDX project. Though I believe the HTML project requires further steps that I haven't investigated.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Using eclipse:

File->Export->Java->JAR File->Export Generated Class Files and Resources

AFAIK You can tell it not to package required libraries with the JAR.